# Android SIP not recording speech

Tags: android, sip, voip

I have problem with SIP android. I don't hear nothing when calls is established. My code:

Initiate call:

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                RefreshView listener = new ConnectingNumberActivity();
                listener.refreshOnCallEstablished();
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                if (call.isMuted()) {
                    call.toggleMute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                stopRigtone();
                endCall();
            }
        };

        sipAudioCall = sipManager.makeAudioCall(sipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress + "@" + domain , listener, 30);
        playRingtone("calling_tone.wav");
        sipAudioCall.toggleMute();
```

Incoming call:

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                try {
                    call.answerCall(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(RINGING_ACTIVITY_TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEnded(call);
                closeIncomingCall();
                PhoneSipManager.stopRigtone();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                super.onCallEstablished(call);

                try {
                    incomingCall.answerCall(30);
                    incomingCall.startAudio();
                    incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                        incomingCall.toggleMute();
                    }

                    PhoneSipManager.sipAudioCall = incomingCall;
                } catch (SipException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
```

and method called after clicked Answer button:

```
private void answerCall() {

    try {
        refreshView();
        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        incomingCall.startAudio();
        incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
        if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
            incomingCall.toggleMute();
        }

        PhoneSipManager.sipAudioCall = incomingCall;

        Log.i(RINGING_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Ringing");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(RINGING_ACTIVITY_TAG, e.toString());

        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code based on WalkieTalkie Android example. Did somebody had the same problem with recording call on first device and nothing hear on the another device?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your permissions.
I was having similar issues but they went away when I set the following permissions and features:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> 

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip.voip" android:required="true" />   
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your answer. Solving the problem was on the VoIP server side.